# print Component B inside component A - vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using Vue.js,
How to create componentA that gets componentB as a prop, and print it inside of it?

**example:**

index.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <componentA :componentPlaceHolder="componentB"></componentA>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import componentA from './compnentA.vue';
import componentB from './componentB.vue'
export default {
    name: 'index',
    components: {componentA,componentB }    
}
</script>
```

componentA.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{componentPlaceHolder}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'componentA',
    props: {
        'componentPlaceHolder': {}
    }    
}
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using dynamic placeholders instead? Something like `<component :is="yourComponentChoice">`

Comment: what's the difference from what i have done? i have printed component A and passed component B as a prop. but i need to print the passed component. it's not really working the way i did it.

Comment: You got your scope wrong: `componentPlaceholder` is in the parent scope, not in the scope of `componentA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues to your implementation:

1. You have gotten the scope wrong: `componentPlaceHolder` lives in the **parent** scope, not in that of component A. Read: [Compilation Scope](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Compilation-Scope).
2. Use `:is` (i.e. `v-bind: is`) for [dynamic component binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components). The data bound should reference the **key** of the component.
3. Since you are nested additional components in another component in the same context, that means you have to **interweave the content**. This is done by using [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots), declared in `<component-a>`.
4. Avoid using case-sensitive DOM elements, use kebab case instead, i.e. `<component-a>` instead of `<componentA>`, since HTML elements are case-insensitive (`<componentA>` and `<componenta>` will be treated the same).

Here is the updated code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <component-a>
            <customComponent :is="componentPlaceHolder"></customComponent>
        </component-a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import componentA from './componentA.vue';
import componentB from './componentB.vue'
export default {
    name: 'index',
    components: {
        'component-a': componentA,
        'component-b': componentB
    },
    data: {
        componentPlaceHolder: 'component-b'
    }
}
</script>
```

And then in your **componentA.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- Slot will interweave whatever that is found in <componentA> -->
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'componentA'  
}
</script>
```

---

### Proof-of-concept example

If in doubt, here is a live proof-of-concept example:

```js
var componentA = {
  template: '#component-a'
};

var componentB = {
  template: '#component-b'
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'component-a': componentA,
    'component-b': componentB
  },
  data: {
    componentPlaceHolder: 'component-b'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component-a>
    <!-- DOM elements in here will be interweaved into <slot> -->
    <customComponent :is="componentPlaceHolder"></customComponent>
  </component-a>
</div>

<template id="component-a">
  <div>
    <p>I am component A</p>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="component-b">
  <p>I am component B</p>
</template>
```

---

### Footnote:

The VueJS readme is exceptionally composed, and I suggest here are some things that you can read up on that is very relevant to your use case:

- [Compilation Scope](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Compilation-Scope)
- [Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)
- [Content Distribution with Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots)